# Is there an easy way to clone the structure of a table in Oracle?

Tags: java, database, oracle

If I have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE FRED
(
recordId number(18) primary key,
firstName varchar2(50)
);
```

Is there an easy way to clone it's structure (not it's data) into another table of a given name. Basically I want to create table with exactly the same structure, but a different name, so that I can perform some functionality on it. I want to do this in code obviously. Java preferably, but most other languages should be similar.

Comment: I'm suspicious of why you want to do this in code -- it's extremely rare for there to be a need to create a table on the fly in Oracle. Perhaps if you give more details we might suggest a way of overcoming the need to do this at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're looking a way to find the exact DDL to recreate the table, including the storage clause, you can use

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'TABLE_NAME', 'SCHEMA_NAME') from dual
```

as described [here](http://www.troygeek.com/articles/ExtractingOracleDDLCommandLine/).

Comment: Nice find. Hadn't seen that before. Any idea what grants you need  to run it?

Comment: I don't have access to Oracle box currently, so I can't test for sure.

Comment: No problem. Just asking out of curiosity rather than need.

Answer (score 6):

CREATE TABLE tablename AS SELECT * FROM orginaltable WHERE 1=2;

Edit: The WHERE clause prohibits any rows from qualifying.

Comment: Won't that copy it's data as well? I just want the structure.

Comment: No rows are copied since 1=2 is always false.  You also will not get any constraints, foreign keys, indexes, etc.

Comment: I accidentally submitted the answer before I put the WHERE clause in there and he got his comment in in the 20 sec it took me to edit. I read the OP as just wanting the table def, not the extras you mention (but thanks for noting it for the OP).

Comment: Hmm, it's not going to preserve the primary key, or any foreign key constraints or check constraints etc.. It will also create it as a completely vanilla table. If you wanted to copy an index organised or partitioned table, or anything exotic, then use DBMS_METADATA.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT INTO TARGET_TABLE FROM SOURCE_TABLE;
OR

CREATE TABLE TARGET_TABLE_NAME AS SELECT * FROM SOURCE_TABLE;
```

if you want to copy only the structure then add the Where Clause `WHERE 1=2`.

I hope it will be helpful.